# A planet with a naturally occurring margarita-like ocean

Tags: science-based, planets, astronomy, ocean, water

I imagined a hypothetical planet named after Bacchus (a nickname given to Dionysus, the Greek god of wine, ecstasy, parties, theatre, drama, comedy, tragedy, and spiritual madness).

Its main characteristic is an ocean composed of a mixture of water, ethanol, and sodium chloride. Also, Bacchus is smaller than Mars but bigger than Mercury. There is a breathable atmosphere. However, there is no life at all.

What would be the conditions for my world to exist? (I ask for a scientific way.)

Comment: Bacchus (= Dionysus) is most definitely a Greek god. (That "ch" is a dead giveaway.) His cult was imported in Rome in the 3rd century BCE, and occasioned a rather [famous religious persecution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Senatus_consultum_de_Bacchanalibus). The corresponding native Roman god was [Liber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liber); eventually, the Romans came to confuse the two divinities. (Greek gods are different from Roman gods in many aspects; one of the most striking differences is that Roman gods are abstract entities, whereas Greek gods routinely mingle and have adventures.)

Comment: "Conditions to exist" would be God (the omnipotent one, not Bacchus or even Jupiter/Zeus) to create it. Are you actually interested in a rather scientific way for this world to come into existence?

Comment: There is the science-based tag for questions where one wants a science based answer

Comment: Accepting an answer within 17 hours seems a bit premature... remember that SO users are found in a wide range of time zones and some of them even have jobs. It is often sensible to wait at least one day, and preferably two, so everyone who might be interested in answering can do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Extremely unlikely but just borderline possible.

Since ethanol evaporates at a lower temperature than water, it may rain ethanol before it rains water. This will not be pleasant, less "champagne shower" and more "metholated spirits in the eyes", and will kill plants and may even stop life from evolving.

Without life, theres no fermentation, which is the easiest way to make ethanol. It also means you cant rely on plants to make oxygen, you need to rely on geology to absorb carbon dioxide and make oxygen.

There is a way to create [ethanol without fermentation](https://news.stanford.edu/news/2014/april/ethanol-without-plants-040914.html) using carbon monoxide, copper derivatives and electricity. I think you need to rely on this.

The rough process would be:

- start with a ball of rock with a carbon dioxide & carbon monoxide atmosphere.
- rock gets hits by ice meteors, giving an ocean.
- ocean dissolves some rock, making salt.
- after weathering, some copper outcrops are exposed.
- static electricity gives lightning impacting the copper and or salt water.
- copper + carbon monoxide + power = ethanol. Ethanol is slowly made over millions of years.
- sub ocean crust slowly dissolves, exposing a carbon sink and releasing oxygen into the water.

The ethanol vapour in the air would be quite potent, its dependent on air pressure and such but I wouldnt want to go there without at least some air filter, otherwise I'd dehydrate and pass out drunk just from breathing the air.

As Williks answer points out; The ethanol would gradually escape the planet, but at the quantities we need for an ocean  it would form ice-like particles along the orbit path, essentially a new ring system of solid ethanol, and ice, some of which would reenter the planet and return to a gas form years later. It wont last for ever but may allow the ethanol ocean to last another few thousand years.

(Queue comments enforcing the point of how unlikely this is to occur)

Comment: The amount of ethanol you'll generate this way seems vanishingly low compared to the size of an ocean or atmosphere. It is still quite a lot higher than the amount of escaped gas that you might expect to have fall back onto your world; it'll form a faint cloud in a more distance orbit around the parent star and be blown away by the solar wind.

Answer (score 6):

**It will be cold on Bacchus.**

[image: escape velocities]

[Here is a fine graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere#Structure) showing escape velocity for various atmospheric gases.  The more massive the planet, the lighter the gas molecules it can hang on to because more massive means higher gravity.  The colder the planet, the more light gas molecules it can hang on to because when it is cold molecules are less frisky.  You stipulate your planet is between Mercury and Mars in size.  Even full Mars size and temperature is too small to hang on to its water, much less ethanol.   Triton is between Mercury and Mars in size and it has kept its water because despite its small size it is freaking cold.

Your ocean of ethanol, salt and water will be frozen all the way down.  Maybe you can breathe the atmosphere with a warming device, and a big one.  On cold days you might need to dig up some atmosphere with a shovel.

Comment: I've been doing a bit of research the background to that particular chart, and I've a sneaking suspicon that it is somewhat misleading. Compare it with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKa3b.png) version which is rather more mathematically sound... an intermediate size world in a Mars-like orbit _might_, in fact, be workable. Note that temperatures on the chart are _exosphere_ temperatures, where available. I might expand on this later.